# IE9 Standards Document Mode Breaks JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have generated some JS code on a web page to calculate the correct amount of days to display on a date drop-down box of a form depending on leap year and month.  Unfortunately, I've noticed that in IE9 Standards Document mode, the drop-down does not appear to display the date numbers (e.g. 1 through 31).  IE 10, Firefox v.25.0.1, and Google Chrome v.31.0.1650.63 display the numbers in the drop-down correctly.  I imagine I have some code that is not supported in older document modes, but cannot seem to find where it would be.  I'm hoping someone may be able to spot my mistake(s)?  I've included the relevant code below.  Please note that I am running the document with the HTML5 !DOCTYPE.

**JS Functions:**

```
<script>
    function is_leap(direction)
    {
        if(direction=="from")
            var year=document.getElementById("f_year").value;
        else if(direction=="to")
            var year=document.getElementById("t_year").value;
        var a = 2000;
        for(a;a<year;a+=4)
        {
        }

        if(a==year)
        {
      return true;
        }
  else return false;
    }

    function out_days(v,direction)
    {
        var html = "";
        for(var x=1;x<=v;x++)
  {
            html += '<option value="' + x + '">' + x + '</option>';
  }
        if(direction=="from")
  {
            var temp_day=document.getElementById("f_day").selectedIndex;
      document.getElementById("f_day").innerHTML=html;  
      document.getElementById("f_day").selectedIndex=temp_day;
  } 
  else if(direction=="to")
  {
      var temp_day=document.getElementById("t_day").selectedIndex;  
            document.getElementById("t_day").innerHTML=html;
      document.getElementById("t_day").selectedIndex=temp_day;
  } 
    }

    function chk_mon(direction)
    {
        if(direction=="from")
      var e = document.getElementById("f_month").selectedIndex;
  else if(direction=="to")
            var e = document.getElementById("t_month").selectedIndex;
        switch(e)
  { 
      case 0: case 2: case 4: case 6: case 7: case 9: case 11:
            {                   
          out_days(31,direction);
    break;
            }
      case 1:
      {
                if(is_leap(direction))
          {
        out_days(29,direction);
          }
          else out_days(28,direction);
    break;
      }
      case 3: case 5: case 8: case 10:
      {
          out_days(30,direction);
    break;
      }
      default:
      {
          out_days(31,direction);
    break;
      }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**HTML Calling Code/Functions:**

```
<div class="field"><div class="label">From:</div><select onchange="chk_mon('from')" id="f_month" name="from_month">
<option value="1">January</option>
<option value="2">February</option>
<option value="3">March</option>
<option value="4">April</option>
<option value="5">May</option>
<option value="6">June</option>
<option value="7">July</option>
<option value="8">August</option>
<option value="9">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option>
</select>
<select id="f_day" name="from_day">
    <script>
        chk_mon("from");
    </script>
</select>
<select onchange="chk_mon('from')" id="f_year" name="from_year">
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
    <option value="2019">2019</option>
    <option value="2020">2020</option>
    <option value="2021">2021</option>
    <option value="2022">2022</option>
    <option value="2023">2023</option>
    <option value="2024">2024</option>
    <option value="2025">2025</option>
    <option value="2026">2026</option>
    <option value="2027">2027</option>
    <option value="2028">2028</option>
    <option value="2029">2029</option>
    <option value="2030">2030</option>
</select></div>
```

Comment: have you tried [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) debugging yet? Also please format the code in your post before posting.

Comment: Also add a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces the issue please.

Comment: What's the error in the console?

Comment: @Mgetz - I have not tried strict mode.  Will give it a try.  In regards to the formatting, I thought I had formatted it, but just noticed some lines were indented more than they should have been.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @Juhana - I wasn't actually getting any errors.  The issue was that the drop-down was not populated with anything as it should have been.

Comment: @George stict mode will help you find strange things faster, it's not guaranteed to solve your problems... but it makes the stupid ones easier to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script there is an assignment of `innerHTML` of `SELECT` element:

```
 document.getElementById("f_day").innerHTML=html;
```

Which does not work in IE9 properly (bug for `SELECT`s). More info [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276228/en-us).

This is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sHQ2f/18/) with possible fix: I wrapped day `SELECT` in `SPAN` and setting `innerHTML` of this `SPAN` instead of `SELECT` in the script.